# Different behavior between dotnet run and dotnet build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a C# project where I have some prebuild and postbuild targets. The prebuild copies some files from a directory outside the project folder into the target directory (using an Exec tag), then the postbuild runs the project (which uses those previously copied in files), generates some more files in the target directory, and then copies these generated files into another directory (still within the target folder). These two steps are also Exec tags, inside the same postbuild target. They look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreEnablePackagesConfig>false</RestoreEnablePackagesConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" Command="xcopy ..\SomeInputFiles\ $(TargetDir)\InputFiles\ /s /e /y" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet $(TargetDir)\My.Project.dll" />
    <Exec Command="xcopy $(TargetDir)\OutputFiles\ $(TargetDir)..\..\..\Output\OutputFiles\ /s /e /y" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

So when I run dotnet build, this is what my folder structure looks like:

```
Project/
├─ src/
├─ target/
│  ├─ distrib/
│  │  ├─ My.Project/
│  │  │  ├─ net6.0/
│  │  │  │  ├─ InputFiles/
│  │  │  │  ├─ OutputFiles/
│  ├─ Output/
│  │  ├─ OutputFiles/
```

The end result is `Project/target/Output` has a bunch of files generated from running the DLL, and `Project/target/Output/OutputFiles` has a bunch of files just like `Project/target/distrib/My.Project/net6.0/OutputFiles` (this second directory is where the files are generated, and then the postbuild Exec task copies them into the first directory).

However, the issue is when I do dotnet run. I get the same folder structure, but `Project/target/Output/OutputFiles` has no files in it, while `Project/target/distrib/My.Project/net6.0/OutputFiles` does have files. It's almost as if `<Exec Command="xcopy $(TargetDir)\OutputFiles\ $(TargetDir)..\..\..\Output\OutputFiles\ /s /e /y" />` just doesn't run (because for `Project/target/distrib/My.Project/net6.0/OutputFiles` to have files in it, `<Exec Command="dotnet $(TargetDir)\My.Project.dll" />` must have executed).

Anyone have any ideas for this difference in behavior?

Comment: Do you delete something before you execute `dotnet run`? Because that should normally imply a `dotnet build` if the project was clean before.

Comment: Not normally no, but for testing purposes I'd delete the entire contents of the target folder before running `dotnet run` or `dotnet build` to make sure it was clean each time (my understanding is that `dotnet run` does a build beforehand, so I'm not sure why there would be any difference in behavior here

Comment: I'm not sure either, but clearing the contents of the target folder may not be enough to trigger a full rebuild, since there are also files in the `obj` folder etc. To trigger a clean rebuild, this should be done using the corresponding method of the version control system (eg. `git clean -dfx`)